# Best practice of useState hook and type script

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm just wondering what would be considered to be best practice when I have multiple elements in my `View` and each of them has some states that can change.

Would it be better to use `useState` hook for each element individually, or to create on general state for the whole screen and have it other sub-states nested inside.

For example something like that:

```
interface InputTextState {
    focused: boolean,
    blurred: boolean,
    value: string,
    hasInvalidValue: boolean
}

interface AcceptButtonState {
   enabled: boolean,
   imgResource: string,
   hasUserClicked: boolean
}

interface ComponentState {
    inputState: InputTextState,
    buttonState: AcceptButtonState
}
```

And then I would just use it like that:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<ComponentState>()
```

When I need to update, I will just update the thing that I need like that

```
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, inputState: {focused: true}))
```

The alternative to this seems to create many states something like that:

```
const [isInputTextBlurred, setIsInputTextBlurred] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
const [isInputTextFocused, setIsInputTextFocused] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
.....
const [hasUserClickedAccept, setHasUserClickedAccept] = React.useState>boolean(false)
```

Comment: It totally depends on your use case. It will always better to use the Interface way.